# Email not sending when NetworkCredential password contains number or special charactor in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, special-characters, smtpclient

I am created a C# Windows Application code for sending Email with attachment.I work successfully when NetworkCredential password contains only alphabetic character. It causes error when password contains alphanumeric character.

My code segment is given below;

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public void email_send()
{
  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
  SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
  mail.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
  mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
  mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
  mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

  System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
  attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/textfile.txt");
  mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

  SmtpServer.Port = 587;
  SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your mail@gmail.com", "your password");
  SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

  SmtpServer.Send(mail);

 }
```

I need your help to send email when  **SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your mail@gmail.com", "your password");** "your password" contains alphanumeric character.

Thank you.

Comment: thats... weird. Can you show an example of the type of password? Not the password itself of course, but something with the same format that is causing difficulty?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: password like 'abc123'